# Searching and downloading data with FAOSTAT

Tags: r, web-scraping

I am trying to use the library `FAOSTAT` and looking for e.g sugar data. I tried to implement the below code, but it is not working.

```
library(FAOSTAT)

fao_metadata <- search_dataset("sugar")
```

Can anybody help how to solve this problem and search data in FAOSTAT by the specific word "sugar" ?